# How to solve "Invalid values for prop `propmethod` on <li> tag." when using SubMenu in another component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd, react-props

I am using SubMenu in another Component as I require State for checkboxes inside Menu. I get this warning when I am passing a method as props to that custom Component I made.

This is the whole warning:

> Invalid values for props `additem`, `selectallzones` on li tag.
> Either remove them from the element, or pass a string or number value
> to keep them in the DOM. For details, see
> (link)

My parent Component looks like this, keep in mind addItem() and selectAllZones() are in this component (I have simplified the code a bit so it only has things that are in question):

```
<SubMenu key="City" title="City">
                            {this.state.cities.map(city => <SubCity key={city.city} city={city} additem={this.addItem} selectallzones={this.selectAllZones}></SubCity>)}
                        </SubMenu>
```

And my SubCity Component looks like this:

```
<SubMenu {...this.props} key={this.props.city.city} title={this.props.city.city}>
                    {this.props.city.zone.map(zone => 
<Menu.Item key={zone.id}><Checkbox disabled={this.state.checkedAll} onChange={(e) => this.props.additem('zones', zone.zone, e)}>{`Zone ${zone.zone}`}</Checkbox></Menu.Item>)}
                </SubMenu>
```

I added the `{...this.props}` in SubMenu component of SubCity looking at another StackOverflow question for other errors I was getting, and I assume this is what is causing the problem. But I can't remove that or my code doesn't run at all. Is there any way I can do this without any warnings in the console? (The code does work, only get a warning in the console.)

Comment: In your SubCity component, did you try `console.log(this.props.additem)` or similar?

Comment: @ChrisG Yeah, the whole method gets logged on the console

Comment: Please provide a [minimal, reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) as Stackblitz or CodeSandbox.